# SQLite layer from AutoCAD MAP in QGIS editing problem

Tags: qgis, sqlite, well-known-binary

SQLite files generated with FDO (AutoCAD MAP) have FGF geometry instead of WKB.  FGF is an extended version of the Well Known Binary (WKB) format. QGIS can read these layers but they can't be edited, so they must be converted in this way:

1. create SQLite in MAP;
2. open SQLite in QGIS;
3. export (convert to WKB) SQLite in QGIS;
4. after that this SQLite works in both programs but its schema must not be changed in MAP or conversion must be done again- not very practical;

My question: is it possible to add to QGIS ability to edit SQLite layers with FGF geometry?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?  I know gdal 2 supports FDO sqlite files so if you are using QGIS 2.14 that might work.

Comment: See https://trac.osgeo.org/fdo/wiki/FDORfc16

Comment: I use qgis 2.14.0-Essen and FDO SQLite can be read but edits are not saved. I add SQLite as vector layer.